# how to use Material React Table in noRecordsToDisplay custom component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-react-table

My Project using table libraruy is [material-react-table](https://www.material-react-table.com/)

When there is no data in the table, I want to render a custom component of table body while including column header

The only type of noRecordsToDisplay is string, is there any other way?

```
noRecordsToDisplay type
noRecordsToDisplay: string;
```

My current code is like this

```
<MaterialReactTable
   enableColumnResizing
   enablePinning
   enableColumnActions={false}
   enableColumnFilters={false}
   enablePagination={false}
   enableBottomToolbar={false}
   enableTopToolbar={false}
   enableFullScreenToggle={false}
   state={{ isLoading: false }}
   localization={{ noRecordsToDisplay: 'No data!!'}}
   {...props}
 />
```

Please give me some advice

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is working properly. It only changes localization of empty state text. I've looked at documentation and didn't find any API or props about specifying empty state component. Have you tried this ? Although documentation said `noRecordsToDisplay` is `String`, I think its worth trying.

```js
<MaterialReactTable
   enableColumnResizing
   enablePinning
   enableColumnActions={false}
   enableColumnFilters={false}
   enablePagination={false}
   enableBottomToolbar={false}
   enableTopToolbar={false}
   enableFullScreenToggle={false}
   state={{ isLoading: false }}

   localization={{ noRecordsToDisplay: <CustomEmptyComponent/> }}
   {...props}
 />
```

Comment: Yes, that's the first thing I tried
But there was a type error

localization={{ noRecordsToDisplay: <renderNoDataComponent /> }}
error message : Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: @moolbum so there is no way to render custom component for this package. You can look up for other package or render another component when there is no data.

Comment: I using `muiTableBodyProps`

<MaterialReactTable
          data={[]}
          muiTableBodyProps={{
            children: <React.Fragment>{renderCustomNoDataComponent()}</React.Fragment>,
          }}/>